# Difference between chage -I and passwd -i

Tags: security, users, password

I'm looking into ways to read and write expiry dates for temporary passwords (i.e.: If we grant users a temporary password and they don't log in and change the temporary password within `N` days, then the account shall be locked).

The documentation for `passwd -i` is

```
-i, --inactive INACTIVE
    This option is used to disable an account after the password has been expired 
    for a number of days. After a user account has had an expired password for
    INACTIVE days, the user may no longer sign on to the account.
```

The documentation for `chage -I` is

```
-I, --inactive INACTIVE
    Set the number of days of inactivity after a password has expired before the
    account is locked. The INACTIVE option is the number of days of inactivity.
    A user whose account is locked must contact the system administrator before
    being able to use the system again.

    Passing the number -1 as the INACTIVE will remove an account's inactivity.
```

The two seem to do the same thing, but they don't reference each other. Does `chage` call `passwd` under the hood or are they actually different?

Comment: They could both be using a library which implements common functionality